# Sorting a list<object> using an array

Tags: c#, winforms, list, sorting

I can't seem to get my head around this.
I have the following:

```
private String[] PREFERED = new String[] { "37", "22", "18" };

    private List<Stream> library;

    public class Stream
    {
        public String ID { get; set; }
        public String URL { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public String Type { get; set; }
    }
```

And I would like to sort the `List<Stream>` named `library` using the `PREFERED` String array so that my result would be the `library` with following order: `35`,`22`,`18`,...

```
library = library.OrderBy(o => Array.IndexOf(PREFERED, o.ID)).ToList();
```

But I'm not getting the expected result...

**JSON**

```
[{"ID":"44","URL":null,"Description":".webm (854x480)","Type":".webm"},
{"ID":"35","URL":null,"Description":".3gp (854x480)","Type":".3gp"},
{"ID":"43","URL":null,"Description":".webm (640x360)","Type":".webm"},
{"ID":"34","URL":null,"Description":".flv (640x360)","Type":".flv"},
{"ID":"18","URL":null,"Description":".mp4 (480x360)","Type":".mp4"},
{"ID":"5","URL":null,"Description":".flv (400x240)","Type":".flv"},
{"ID":"36","URL":null,"Description":".flv (400x240)","Type":".flv"},
{"ID":"17","URL":null,"Description":".3gp (176x144)","Type":".3gp"}]
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: Is the discrepancy in the first element (`37` vs `35`) also present in your code?

Comment: I believe this should work given all the ID is guaranteed to exist, however if not found `IndexOf` returns minus 1 which would bump a non-existent ID to the front of the list.

Comment: Post the sample which doesn't works for you

Comment: I tried this on my machine, and it works just fine. Just not that all IDs that does not exist in PREFERED will be added to the start of the List since IndexOf return -1 for them.

Comment: I think @KevinDiTraglia is on track... I'll see if I can cleanup my PREFERED array first to remove non-existant IDs

Comment: @grmbl how are you deserializing your JSON? It looks like your `ID` fields are actually `int`'s not `string`'s and should be treated as such.

Comment: You should verify the text and data in the question (35/37) and describe what's wrong there.

Comment: @james, the ID's are strings, I believe the JSON.Net library converts them to int automatically?

Comment: @grmbl only if that's the data type in the model allows. In your case it will keep them as string because you have `ID` declared as one!

Comment: I would like to know why this Q is getting  -4 votes down... :(

Comment: @grmbl: I didn't downvote you but I can understand why you get downvoted. You haven't shown a complete example explaining the problem. You ask for the following order "35,22,18" but that's already the output that you get with your actual code. And your JSON isn't helpful because you don't give the expected output. Your problem is that you want non-preferred items at the end of the list, and you didn't even state it in your question, we had to guess it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works even for cases where `PREFERED` doesn't contain the IDs in `library`.

```
var ranks =
    PREFERED
        .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
        .ToLookup(xn => xn.x, xn => xn.n);

library =
    library
        .OrderBy(l =>
            ranks[l.ID]
                .DefaultIfEmpty(int.MaxValue)
                .First())
        .ToList();
```

---

Here is the explanation, as per request int he comments.

The line `.Select((x, n) => new { x, n })` projects the sequence of values into a sequence of the values and their index in the sequence.

The line `.ToLookup(xn => xn.x, xn => xn.n)` changes the sequence into a dictionary-like structure that returns a list of zero or more values from any key provided, regardless if the key was in the original sequence or not. If the key was not in the original sequence you get an empty sequence of values in return.

The expression `ranks[l.ID]` takes each id in the `library` sequence and applies the lookup, return a sequence of values. The expression `.DefaultIfEmpty(int.MaxValue)` ensures that the sequence has at least one value, and the expression `.First()` returns the first value of the sequence. So this ensures that for ever id in the `library` source you get the possible matching index value from the `PREFERED` sequence, or `int.MaxValue` if the id was not in the `PREFERED` sequence.

Then it is a simple matter of ordering by the returned value and recreating the list with `.ToList()`.

Comment: Could you explain this solution step by step?

Comment: @grmbl - I've added an explanation as per your request.

Answer (score 1):

I tried following code in Linqpad and it worked for me:

```
void Main()
{
String[] PREFERED = new String[] { "37", "22", "18" };
List<Stream> library =  new  List<Stream> () ;
library.Add (new Stream () {ID ="22" }) ;
library.Add (new Stream () {ID ="37" }) ;
library.Add (new Stream () {ID ="18" }) ;
library.Dump () ;
library.OrderBy(o => Array.IndexOf(PREFERED, o.ID)).ToList().Dump () ;

}

public class Stream
{
    public String ID { get; set; }
    public String URL { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try this in Linqpad (I just did):

`void Main()
{
String[] PREFERED = new String[] { "18", "22", "37" };
List<Stream> library =  new  List<Stream> () ;
library.Add (new Stream () {ID ="22" }) ;
//library.Add (new Stream () {ID ="37" }) ;
library.Add (new Stream () {ID ="18" }) ;
library.Add (new Stream () {ID ="33" }) ;
library.Dump () ;
library.OrderBy(o => Array.IndexOf(PREFERED, o.ID)).ToList().Dump () ;

}

public class Stream
{
    public String ID { get; set; }
    public String URL { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Type { get; set; }
}`

Comment: Getting element containing ID=33 in top of list. This Id does not exist in PREFERED

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you just want them to go in descending order based on the `ID` field, why not do

```
library = library.OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(x.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: Because `"22"` is greater than `"18"` / Based on the name, the descending order is most likely coincidence.

Comment: _parsing the string to an int_ - very questionable for a `string Id` field.

Comment: The `""` makes them very much look like strings to me. So does the declaration.

Comment: @HenkHolterman well the fact every ID is integer *data*, they look like `int`'s in a `string` property. If the `ID` is not always an integer then of course this isn't the right approach but from the information given I think it's a valid answer.

Comment: 3 samples don't make it safe. A string is a string until a clear spec is provided saying that it's always numerical.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think the OP's JSON pretty much confirms that they are `int`'s.

Comment: The ID's were initially int but I changed them to String because I thought that would be a cause of my problem.

Comment: @grmbl not a good idea, if data is `int` then it should be treated as such. My advice would be to convert them back and use my solution, it will work.

Comment: @james, I've changed back my PREFERED from String array to int array + also property ID. I agree that it made more sense.. :)
Now I'm thinking about how to remove IDs from PREFERED that are not present in library...

Comment: @grmbl something like `var preferred = library.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct()` should work (assuming you just want `preferred` to be all unique ID's in the library).

Comment: @james, will this not destroy the purpose of PREFERED? (having a int array with the ID order I'd like to have on library)

Comment: @grmbl that's what you asked "*Now I'm thinking about how to remove IDs from PREFERED that are not present in library...*" - the code I suggested will do that. However, looking at your problem as a whole, I would recommend you add a `DisplayOrder` property and sort the list by that instead, using the `ID` field is the problem here. You need to handle when item's are no longer in the list etc.

Comment: @james, I thought that was something I needed to do because of Kevin's comment.